# 301 Redirect not working from Google results link

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, trailing-slash

My htaccess 301 redirects work if I type the url without a trailing slash like...

www.nicksplumbing.com/water-heater

If I use a trailing slash like...

www.nicksplumbing.com/water-heater/

The redirect adds a trailing slash after the new pages url like .html/ resulting in a 404.

This is a serious issue for me because old Google results have the trailing slash and are being 404'd and not redirected.

Here is my htaccess:

Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://www.nicksplumbing.com/404.html

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^nicksplumbingrepair.com$ [OR]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.nicksplumbingrepair.com$ [OR]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^nicksplumbing.com

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.nicksplumbing.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]

Redirect 301 /plumbing-company-houston http://www.nicksplumbing.com/plumbers-in-houston.html

Redirect 301 /reviews http://www.nicksplumbing.com/houston-plumbing-company-reviews.html

Redirect 301 /leaky-faucet http://www.nicksplumbing.com/leaky-dripping-faucet-repair-houston.html

Redirect 301 /garbage-disposal http://www.nicksplumbing.com/garbage-disposal-repair-installation-houston.html

Redirect 301 /plumbing-repair http://www.nicksplumbing.com/plumbing-services-houston.html

Redirect 301 /repipe http://www.nicksplumbing.com/repipe-house-specialists-houston.html

Redirect 301 /sewer-repair http://www.nicksplumbing.com/sewer-line-repair-houston.html

Redirect 301 /toilet-clogged http://www.nicksplumbing.com/running-leaking-toilet-repair-houston.html

Redirect 301 /water-heater http://www.nicksplumbing.com/water-heater-repair-installation-houston.html

Redirect 301 /blog http://www.nicksplumbing.com/nicks-plumbing-blog.html

Redirect 301 /contact-us http://www.nicksplumbing.com/contacts.html
```

Can someone please help?!
Desperate to find the cause as I don't want to lose any link juice.

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

Needed do a Directory to Html redirect.

RedirectMatch 301 ^/water-heater(.*) http://www.nicksplumbing.com/water-heater-repair-installation-houston.html